# Where is the next mission after Shrine of Oryx?

Tags: destiny

I just started playing Destiny, and am following the main story line. I finished the mission "[Shrine of Oryx](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Shrine_of_Oryx)", and returned to the tower. I see the little "go to" icons, but they just lead me around in circles.

Where should I be going, next?

Comment: there are a bunch of "go to" icons in the tower.. but they are not mission directives. They are just to direct you around the tower; sign posts. Mission directives should be colourful, signposts should be grey. What colour are yours?

Comment: @CloseVoters, Detiny has a pretty linear story line. In terms of the main story, there is only one direction for "next". I feel another user will be able to answer this quite quickly, OP. Just in case, I might also enquire about how many planets you see on your starting map. I know that with the addition of Taken King, it is possible to "unlock all the levels" before the story takes you there, which can make it  a bit harder to identify the next point of call.

Comment: I think this is a valid question as TTK has made the mission flow (particularly for the main campaign) much less intuitive.

Comment: "yo dawg I heard yo like story missions. So I opened up all the story missions, so you can get confused, and have to revisit the same ones again, later"

Comment: @Timelord64 as long as they are not putting missions inside missions, so you can play missions while you are playing missions, I think it's fine

Answer (score 1):

(This is in case when the questions stays, else just delete my answer. I however think this is a legitmate question since the changes from TTK)

With the TTK rework they changed some of the story flow, however i think there are two options left. You completed the "Shrine of Oryx", which means you cleared the "[Sword of Crota](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/The_Sword_of_Crota)" mission (it is a prerequisite). The only mission left to do on the Moon is "[Chamber of Night](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Chamber_of_Night)", which also has Sword of Crota as prerequisite (as far as i know, there is a [Dark Below](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/The_Wakening) mission, but it should come later). Now if you have done that one before the Shrine mission, the other option is you have to go to [next planet](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/A_Stranger%27s_Call) (Spoiler!).

PS:

> One of the dialog in Chamber of Night is: 
> "GHOST: Signal dropped. I got some broken coordinates--Venus, Northern Hemisphere. Ishtar region. Great. What do we do now?" And the next mission takes place on Venus. I am guessing he is stuck between the planet change

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is your first play through and that the next mission is Strangers Call on Venus. This mission is player level locked.
[Info Source](http://uk.ign.com/wikis/destiny/A_Stranger%27s_Call).

> Location           Level Requirement Fireteam      Rewards (Hard Mode)
>      Ishtar Sink, Venus 10                1-3 Players   XP Bonus +3000, Armor Upgrade